# How to extend TableSort class

Tags: 7, database

I have a paged table that extends the TableSort class. The thing is, I would like to add some special parameters to the header links, so I need to extend the TableSort class. The problem is, it is not recognizing my new extended TableSort (MyTableSort) class. This is the code, any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
<?php
// $Id: RadiosDemo.module $
//This module demonstrates the radios default value problem.

class MyTableSort extends TableSort {
/**
* Compose a URL query parameter array for table sorting links.
*
* @return
*   A URL query parameter array that consists of all components of the current
*   page request except for those pertaining to table sorting.
*/
  public function tablesort_get_query_parameters() {
    return drupal_get_query_parameters($_GET, array('q', 'sort', 'order', 'nid'));
  }
}

/**
* Implementation of hook_menu().
*/
function RadiosDemo_menu() {

  // Added a link to navigate to the demo node display page
  $items['RadiosDemo/Problem'] = array(
    'title' => 'Demo of Pager Problem',
    'page callback' => 'RadiosDemo_displaynodes',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );

  return $items;
}

/**
 * Function which will display all the nids in a paged table
 */
function RadiosDemo_displaynodes() {

  $headers = array(
    array('data' => 'nid', 'field' => 'nid', 'sort' => 'ASC'),
    array('data' => 'status', 'field' => 'status'),
    array('data' => 'title', 'field' => 'title'),
  );

  // Select nid from published nodes with 20 pager limit
  $query = db_select('node', 'n')
    ->condition('status', 1)
    ->extend('MyTableSort')
    ->extend('PagerDefault')
    ->orderByHeader($headers)
    ->limit(30)
    ->fields('n', array('nid', 'title', 'status'));

  $results = $query->execute();

  $rows = array();

  foreach ($results as $result) {
    $row = array();
    $row[] = $result->nid;
    $row[] = $result->status;
    $row[] = $result->title;

    $rows[] = $row;
  }

  $html = theme('table', array(
   'header' => $headers,
   'rows' => $rows,
  ));

  $html .= theme('pager', array(
    'parameters' => array(
      'banana' => 'banana'
  )));

  return $html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like any other extender, the [TableSort](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!tablesort.inc/class/TableSort/7) class implements the [SelectQueryInterface](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/interface/SelectQueryInterface/7) interface.

Your code doesn't work because [tablesort_get_query_parameters()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!tablesort.inc/function/tablesort_get_query_parameters/7) is a Drupal function, not a method defined from `SelectQueryInterface`. To change the behavior of an extender, you need to re-define one of the methods listed in the documentation for [SelectQueryInterface](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/interface/SelectQueryInterface/7).

#### References

- [Extenders](http://drupal.org/node/508796)

Comment: So basically, this means, that I can't extend function tablesort_get_query_parameters() because its not listed in the SelectQueryInterface methods right?  So how could I possibly add another parameter to the table header links then?